# Amplifying microvolt difference between 2 constant analog signals (0-1V)

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-design, photodiode

I have 2 UV light sensors for detecting ozone gas with the circuitry uploaded in the picture. I don't fully understand how it works, but the signal output is the current going through the photodiode in µA multiplied by 4.3.

[image: https://www.hestore.hu/prod_10039317.html]

https://www.hestore.hu/prod_10039317.html

The base output will be somwhere around 0.5V.
Effectively I'd have to measure the difference in light intensity with 0.005% accuracy with both sensors. Their outputs are unfortunately not related to each other.

Is there any way I could relatively easily amplify that signal so that the 0.005% of the 0.5V (25µV) is at least in the mV range? That way my Teensy 4.0 microcontroller can process the data. (Note the signal is not a waveform.)

I am new to electronics and the most complicated thing I've made so far was an LED driver circuit with a MOSFET as a switch.

Comment: Where did you get that 4.3 V/uA factor from? It's way higher than that with the values shown, more like 4.3nA/V. You should also credit the image source, in keeping with the rules of this site.

Comment: The schematic is from the manufacturer's site, I've pasted the link below the image (However I'm not sure it is of any use)

Comment: @BarnabasSzupkay  50 ppmv ***accuracy***!? Slapping down a schematic is the last thing. Start by understanding your experimental setup, sensors, and their interactions over whatever specified range (and, hopefully, this isn't a dynamic range that spans orders of magnitude.)

Comment: @periblepsis I was talking about the link not the schematic

Comment: @BarnabasSzupkay I'm talking about how I read ***"have to measure the difference in light intensity with 0.005% accuracy with both sensors"***.

Comment: *The schematic is from the manufacturer's site* The fact that the schematic is a piece of crap may hint somewhat at what sort of a quality of a sensor you have here. All you got at this point are pieces you'll have to design into an actual sensor. Why do you even assume that the photodiodes have any chance of performing to the level you want? Parts qualified and characterized to that level of performance cost on the order of $100-$1k, and come in fancy packaging. I doubt that's what you have here :) Are the photodiodes even genuine? How would you know? Who stands behind the parts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'd have to measure the *difference* in light intensity with 0.005% accuracy with both sensors [emphasis mine]

The 0.005% accuracy sought generally requires thermostatic control of the photodiodes and the PCB, component selection and burn-in, cleanliness in PCB assembly, and lots of attention to detail in general. This is not a circuit that a beginner will have any chance at to the level you claim you need.

But I don't know whether you need this accuracy at all. 0.1% would be plenty already for many applications, and is more realistic. Don't assume you'll get any better than that without some significant R&D effort. To start with, you'll need to have UV light sources with intensity calibrated to this accuracy, or a calibrated measurement setup to measure each source's output. 0.005%-level changes can come from stuff so "innocent" as optical coatings changing their properties with temperature changes. It's *not* an easy problem, and requires metrology skills - whether pre-existing, or acquired on the job the hard way.

We're talking **expensive** equipment here. Anyone without a lab doing that as a consulting job would have to rent many $10k worth of equipment to pull it off to 0.005% absolute accuracy. Do you have access to all that? How will you quantify the performance of your circuit? Remember: you need to quantify sensor aging, temperature- and humidity-induced drift, and so on. Without an environmental chamber, or very well characterized parts, there's no way to claim that this will retain any better than a couple % absolute accuracy over say 5-50C temperature and 10%-90% humidity range.

---

I usually try to avoid such problems by not having to deal with amplifying differential pair signals to begin with - if possible. What you're looking for is a differential photodiode circuit. It will inherently take a photocurrent difference, so you won't have to amplify the common mode signal, and the difference will be inherent in the design.

Something like below would be a reasonable starting point.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs6wP6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A circuit similar to the above is about what you can get while keeping things cheap and uncomplicated, using general purpose components.

Photodiodes D1 and D2 are in a differential connection. Op-amp OA1, through resistor R1, provides the differential current to balance the photodiode common point at 1/2 of the input common mode range. The output of OA1 is scaled 1V/μA of differential photodiode current.

Additional gain is provided by OA2, with the output being scaled 1V/100nA of differential photodiode current.

LMV358's input common mode range is from 0V to VCC-1V, so up to about 2.3V with 3.3V supply. The common mode voltage reference COM is at half of the input common mode range, so about 1.1V.

RV1 is used to null the offset current errors to bring the output within range.

If the circuit were to be powered from +5V, R3 would have to be adjusted so that there would be about 1.1V across it.

And no, you definitely do not want to use the circuit that "came with" the sensors. It just doesn't fit the application you have in mind.

The layout of this circuit is fairly critical, and a continuous ground plane is recommended on the bottom layer, with a cutout around the inverting OA1 node, as well as guard traces around the inverting node of OA1, on both sides of the board (and any internal layers). The guard should be around the common point of R1, C1, D1, D2, and R6. To make this easier, R6, R1, C1 should be at least 0805-sized parts, or even 1206, so that the guard trace will easily fit between the terminals.

Also remember that this is essentially a DC circuit. It will react to slow changes in differential photocurrent, and that's that. I'm not sure what your exact measurement setup is. It is certainly a good idea to have a differential measurement. But for that to work, D1 and D2 have to be very well thermally coupled. I'd install them perhaps in a line, and make the common node (OA1:-) a large chunk of copper to thermally bond the photodiodes as much as practical.

A large chunk of this circuit will have to be shielded, as indicated by the dashed line. Otherwise, it'll measure you waving a hand close to it in low humidity conditions about as well as it will measure minute changes in differential light levels.

The 2nd, unused op-amp from OA1 package should be connected as a voltage follower for the COM signal, its output otherwise unused.

OA2 should be a separate op-amp chip, otherwise you may get oscillation. Since LMV358 is a rather low-current part, the power supply for it can be well decoupled with an RC low-pass filter.

Answer (score 2):

The transimpedance gain is way higher than you suggest.

I could show you how to subtract two voltages with a differential amplifier, but I don't think measuring this circuit's output to a tiny percentage is going to be very successful- this is not a precision circuit, maybe good to a few percent on a good day (by that I mean with 'typical' performance, not worst case). The output of two such circuits will not be matched and will vary with temperature from air currents and such like when you get down to uV. The slightest bit of dirt will change the values.

Maybe you can find a way to use a single sensor and chop the signal mechanically or some approach of that ilk.

Comment: I can desolder the photodiode and use a different op amp if that helps, also I can definitely use 1 sensor only, but then the waveforms peak will remain almost constant, whereas the trough will change

Comment: @BarnabasSzupkay Start by telling us how you'll clean your prototypes after soldering. You're looking at a circuit with resolution of a fraction of 1nA. You can get leakages of that order just by breathing close to a PCB with flux or other contamination on it, never mind galvanic effects as the contaminants absorb moisture from the atmosphere. There are differential UV sensors with specs you seem to want. ~$1k will get you one, but you'll get exactly what you paid for. Are you sure you can replicate the engineering needed to get that level of performance for less money?